# tcpreplay: -T option

Tags: tcp, udp, ip, ethernet, packet-injection

In `tcpreplay` there is a very useful feature which, according to the [official FAQ's](http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/wiki/FAQ#Packetlength8892isgreaterthenMTUskippingpacket), is called with parameter `-T` :

> The packet length (in this case 8892 bytes) is greater then the
>   maximum transmition unit (MTU) on the outgoing interface. Tcpreplay
>   must skip the packet. Alternatively, you can specify the **-T option** and
>   **tcpreplay will truncate the packet to the MTU size, fix the checksums
>   and send it**.

Unfortunately, `-T` appears to be something different in the man page:

```
-T string, --timer=string
              Select packet timing mode: select, ioport, rdtsc, gtod, nano, abstime.  This option may appear up to 1 times.  The default string for this option is:
                   gtod
              Allows you to select the packet timing method to use:
              nano - Use nanosleep() API
              select - Use select() API
              ioport - Write to the i386 IO Port 0x80
              rdtsc - Use the x86/x86_64/PPC RDTSC
              gtod [default] - Use a gettimeofday() loop
              abstime - Use OS X's AbsoluteTime API
```

Has this option been **removed** in more recent versions of tcpreplay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it was separated into [`tcprewrite`](http://tcpreplay.appneta.com/wiki/tcprewrite-man.html) (which transforms capture files) and then the options were merged back in the command `tcpreplay-edit`.

The [FAQ](http://tcpreplay.appneta.com/wiki/faq.html#packet-length-8892-is-greater-then-mtu-skipping-packet) shows `tcpreplay-edit --mtu-trunc` is now the equivalent of the previous `-T` option and should imply `-C` to correct the checksum, but you may need `--mtu=n` if you aren't dealing with a standard 1500 or need `-F` if part of the problem is inconsistent header and real length at collection time.